# How to make custom operators in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a class to write logs. And I want to replace std::cout to my own class.

like below:

```
LogWriter lw;
lw << "LOG: TEST" << lw.endl;
```

I made print function, but [lw.endl] command doesn't work.

#### <logwriter.h>

```
namespace logwriter {

    class LogWriter {
    public:
        LogWriter();
        ~LogWriter();

        LogWriter& operator<<(std::string str);

        LogWriter& operator<<(LogWriter& (*pf)(LogWriter& lw));

        LogWriter& endl(LogWriter& lw);
    };
}
```

#### <logwriter.cpp>

```
namespace logwriter {
    LogWriter& LogWriter::operator<<(std::string str) {
        std::cout << std;
        return *this;
    }
    LogWriter& LogWriter::operator<<(LogWriter& (*pf)(LogWriter& lw)) {
        return pf(*this);
    }
    LogWriter& LogWriter::endl(LogWriter& lw) {
        *this << "\n";
        return *this;
    }
}
```

#### <main.cpp>

```
void main() {
    logwriter::LogWriter lw;
    lw << "LOG: TEST" << lw.endl;
}
```

> Error C3867   'logwriter::LogWriter::endl': non-standard syntax; use '&'
> to create a pointer to
> member    LogWriter   C:\Users\jsm890803\source\repos\LogWriter\LogWriter\main.cpp    31
> Error (active)    E0300   a pointer to a bound function may only be used to
> call the
> function  LogWriter   C:\Users\jsm890803\source\repos\LogWriter\LogWriter\main.cpp    31
> Error C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand
> operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable
> conversion)   LogWriter   C:\Users\jsm890803\source\repos\LogWriter\LogWriter\main.cpp    31

How could I modify this to run correctly?

Comment: Note that the expected syntax is `lw << " ... " << endl;`, not `... << lw.endl;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code (as it is standard) `operator<<` is overloaded for a function pointer.

```
LogWriter& LogWriter::operator<<(LogWriter& (*pf)(LogWriter& lw)) {...}
```

`lw.endl` is not a function pointer, (neither is `lw.endl()`) in this line:

```
lw << "LOG: TEST" << lw.endl;
```

As a matter of fact `endl`, at most, is a member function pointer, which behaves differently than a function pointer (pointer to free function).

What you need to so is to make `endl` a plain function, for example a class-static one.

```
static LogWriter& endl(LogWriter& lw);
```

(Note that even outside this context a function like this taking an argument of the same type doesn't make sense as a member function.)

In this way, the semantics of

```
lw << "LOG: TEST" << LogWriter::endl;
```

Is basically:

```
LogWriter::endl( lw << "LOG: TEST" );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I solved it after adding "static" in front of the function.